# Motivation for $y(x - y) = \frac{1}{2}(x^2 - y^2) - \frac{1}{2}(x-y)^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

It's a really simple identity and according to the text, I am reading, this is an obvious identity

$$y(x - y) = \frac{1}{2}(x^2 - y^2) - \frac{1}{2}(x-y)^2$$

Without expanding the RHS, I don't know how they came up with this.

Comment: Factor out $\;x-y\;$ in the RHS...

Comment: Ohh hoho. OKay, it's not so cryptic anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are just some common identities which everyone will come across once in a while.

Given left hand side and the requirements, you should be able to find the most common identities to which it can be converted. As with this case, it is very much similar to $xy$ which can be written as:
$$ \frac{(x+y)^2 - (x-y)^2}{4}  $$

Similarly $y(x-y)$, can be written as :
$$ (x-y)\frac{(x+y-(x-y))}{2}$$
which on further simplification gives :
$$ \frac{(x^2 - y^2)}{2}-\frac{(x-y)^2}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

Factor the first term on the right hand side: $\frac{1}{2} (x^2-y^2) = \frac{1}{2} (x+y)(x-y).$ Factor the second term: $(x-y)^2=(x-y)(x-y)$ since squaring a number is defined to be the product of that number with itself.

Then factor out $(x-y)$ from $\frac{1}{2} (x+y)(x-y)-\frac{1}{2}(x-y)(x-y)$ since it is a common term (remember to think of parenthetical expressions like $(x-y)$ as SINGLE terms). You should get the left hand side from there.